# Properties of the product of a complex matrix with its complex conjugate transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on a paper and I have a complex-valued $N \times K$ matrix $A$ and its complex conjugate transpose $A^*$. What happens when I take a product $A A^*$? What does the property state what happens when I multiply them other than having a real-valued matrix?

Here N>>K

Comment: is the matrix square? Thin? Fat? Full column rank? Full row rank?

Comment: N>>Kso it makes A a thin matrix

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo N>>K so it makes A a thin matrix

Comment: The product is Hermitian and positive semidefinite.

Comment: If $\mathrm A^* \mathrm A = \mathrm I$, then $\mathrm A \mathrm A^*$ is a **projection matrix**. In that case, the trace of $\mathrm A \mathrm A^*$ equals its rank.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo isnt taking a complex conjugate transpose same as taking a hermatian??????

Answer (score 1):

It may be instructive to look at the SVD of $A$. Let

$$
A = U
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
V^*,
$$

where $\Sigma$ is the $K\times K$ diagonal matrix of singular values. Then

$$
AA^* = U
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma^2 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
U^*
= \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i^2 u_iu_i^*,
$$
where $r \leq K$ is the rank of $A$. Thus, the rank of $AA^*$ is equal to the rank of $A$, its column space is the span of $U_{1:r}$ (the same as $A$), and its nullspace is the span of $U_{r+1:N}$.

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for but I hope it helps.

Comment: no i was not looking for this answer all i want to know is what does this product represents for example if we take a derivative of something we find its slope/rate of change